# Meteor: Blaze.Each example

Tags: meteor, foreach, meteor-blaze

How can one use `Blaze.Each`? For example, I'd like to emulate this:

```
{{#each Items}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

in JS. I need to keep reactivity.

Something like:

```
Blaze.Each(Items.find(), function(item) {
 console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get previous answer

**This**

html

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
    <div id="each-area">
    </div> 
</template>
```

js

```
Template.yourTemplate.onRendered(function () {
    var renderableContent = Blaze.Each(Collection.find({}), function(){
        return Template.templateToRender;
    });
    Blaze.render(renderableContent, this.find("#each-area"));
});
```

**Is complete equivalent of this:**

html

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
    <div id="each-area">
        {{#each data}}
           {{>templateToRender}}
        {{/each}}
    </div> 
</template>
```

js

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    "data": function(){
        return Collection.find({})
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.autorun(function(){
    var items = Items.find(); 
     _.each(items.fetch(), function(item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

This works. It console.logs everytime an Item is added.

w/o underscore and autorun:

```
Blaze.Each(Data.find().fetch(), function(item){ 
    console.log(item) 
})
```

Comment: this wouldn't be reactive, I think that's the whole point of `Blaze.Each` - otherwise one could use `_.each` / `.forEach` etc!

Comment: Using autorun would make it reactive. I'm not too sure why you'd want to `return console.log()`, I've updated the code which only logs.

Comment: ah, I had tried `autorun` and it didn't work - something else was breaking it. thanks. I'll leave the question open for a few days because I'm still curious as to what `Blaze.Each` is for.

Comment: Hey, I wasn't aware of Blaze.Each actually.

`Blaze.Each(Items.find().fetch(), function(i){ console.log(i) })` is actually reactive w/o `autorun`!

Comment: I can't reproduce that. also, `.fetch()` is non-reactive?

Comment: .fetch() is not reactive. 
Blaze.Each is probably tracking the return value. Not much information at http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html
Could you check the meteorpad at http://meteorpad.com/pad/Wp9qZR9w5NEXg5Jzv/SO%2030730060 
Running `Items.insert({ name: "Item A" })`, `Items.insert({ name: "Item B" })`, etc on the console, logs the entire list of items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80063/discussion-between-offthegrass-and-kaoskeya).